# How do I Map a List of Maps into a List of my Custom Class?

Tags: flutter, dart, types, casting

I am trying to map a List of Maps into a List of Objects of my Custom "Address" Class.
However, if I run my code, i get this error:

```
I/flutter (26434): type 'CastList<dynamic, List<Address>>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Address>'
```

This is my SourceCode:
listOfMaps is the List of Maps I pull from a database;

```
List<Address> _userAddresses;
_userAddresses = listOfMaps.map((address) {
    return Address(
      firstName: address["firstName"],
      lastName: address["lastName"],
      streetname: address["streetname"],
      houseNumber: address["houseNumber"],
      zipCode: address["zipCode"],
      city: address["city"],
      country: address["country"],
      state: address["state"],
    );
  }).toList().cast<List<Address>>();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm supposing `listOfMaps` is `List<dynamic>` then you can do this:

```
var _userAddresses = listOfMaps.map<Address>((m) => Address.fromJson(m)).toList();
```

Where:

```
Address.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> jdata) { ... }
```

I hope it to help you.